# Why do I get transparent hover labels on my second plotly plot in rmarkdown?

Tags: r, firefox, r-markdown, plotly

This is Albert posting for the first time in stackoverflow :)

So my problem is that, when generating two plotly plots in a row the second one do not show the hover labels properly. Instead of taking the dot colour, they appear with white font and transparent background. Even when using the same function call, and the same code, the error still appears. The first call though, works fine so the first plot is generated with correct labels. **The error only appears when using Firefox as browser**. In other browsers, like safari and the internal Rstudio browser, **the error does not show up.** This is specially annoying because I need to send the reports (html) to collaborators who may use Firefox or other browsers. So I really need to make sure that it works.

I use Windows 10 and Firefox quantum 59.0.2 (64-bit)

Here is a picture showing the error, highlighted in a red rectangular
[image]
[transparent hoover labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nqaT.png)

Reproducible example:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(plotly)
my_plotly <- function(my_data){

  p1 <- plot_ly(data = my_data, x = ~disp, y = ~hp, 
                color = ~drat, size = ~gear,
                text = ~rownames(my_data))
  p1 
}

```

```{r, echo=F, error=F, warning=F, message=F}
my_plotly(my_data = mtcars)
my_plotly(my_data = mtcars)
sessionInfo()
```
````

sessioninfo:

```
## R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
## Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
## Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 16299)
## 
## Matrix products: default
## 
## locale:
## [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
## [2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
## [3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
## [4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
## [5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    
## 
## attached base packages:
## [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
## 
## other attached packages:
## [1] bindrcpp_0.2.2 plotly_4.7.1   ggplot2_2.2.1 
## 
## loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
##  [1] Rcpp_0.12.16        pillar_1.2.1        compiler_3.4.3     
##  [4] plyr_1.8.4          bindr_0.1.1         tools_3.4.3        
##  [7] digest_0.6.15       jsonlite_1.5        evaluate_0.10.1    
## [10] tibble_1.4.2        gtable_0.2.0        viridisLite_0.3.0  
## [13] pkgconfig_2.0.1     rlang_0.2.0         shiny_1.0.5        
## [16] crosstalk_1.0.0     yaml_2.1.18         dplyr_0.7.4        
## [19] stringr_1.3.0       httr_1.3.1          knitr_1.20         
## [22] htmlwidgets_1.0     rprojroot_1.3-2     grid_3.4.3         
## [25] glue_1.2.0          data.table_1.10.4-3 R6_2.2.2           
## [28] rmarkdown_1.9       purrr_0.2.4         tidyr_0.8.0        
## [31] magrittr_1.5        backports_1.1.2     scales_0.5.0       
## [34] htmltools_0.3.6     assertthat_0.2.0    xtable_1.8-2       
## [37] mime_0.5            colorspace_1.3-2    httpuv_1.3.6.2     
## [40] stringi_1.1.7       lazyeval_0.2.1      munsell_0.4.3
```

Comment: Can reproduce this on my MAC with the same Firefox version, but no idea how to solve this.

Comment: I can not reproduce this.  `Firefox 59.0.2 (64-bit)`, `plotly 4.7.1.9000`